# Как из активности передать String в обычный класс, а потом эту String передать в другую активность

Tags: классы, activity, android-intent

В первой активности есть список месяцев, по нажатии на один из них хочу передать это значение через String в класс с базой данных,

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {

                как передать в класс с базой данных?
            }
        }
    });`
```

получив этот стринг занести его в метод `public Cursor getData() {

```
    selectionArgs = new String[]{"9"};//если писать так, то только отображается 9 месяц
    selection = "month = ?";
    orderBy = "day";
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
}`
```

Спасибо!

Comment: а что мешает создать объект этого типа в активити, и через курсор получить нужный string?то же самое проделать во второй активити - вы ведь с бд работаете.

Comment: При создании списка месяцев базу данных не использую. Список получаю из ресурсов.